# How to center my bokeh plot

Tags: python, html, css, plot, bokeh

I currently have this plot which is a bit to the right. i wish to move to the center. How can i change my css code.

[image: bokeh plot]

my code is:

```
{% include "base.html" %}

{% block page_content %}

<style>
    <!--#graphs {-->
  <!--width: 50%;-->
  <!--margin: 0 auto;-->
<!--}-->

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; /* !!! */
}

.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 800px;
}


</style>

{{ js_resources|safe }}
{{ css_resources|safe }}
<div id="graphs" class="centered">
    {{ plot_div|safe }}
    {{ plot_script|safe }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Is there something wrong with my css?

**EDIT**
this is the new style

```
<style>


body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;  !!! 
}

.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 800px;
}


</style>
```

and this is the resulting firebug

[image: update style]

**EDIT 2**

this is the body style

[image: update style 2]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the *.centered* class to the following :

```css
    .centered {
      display : block;
      margin : 0 auto;
      text-align: left;
      width: 800px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="centered" style="background-color : red; width : 300px; height : 100px;">
<p>Here is your centered graph :)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Press F12 in your browser, and verifiy in the CSS properties that the display : block; and margin : 0 auto; are not overlined.

Comment: The screen shows only the CSS properties on the body element. We need the properties applied on the .centered element. To do so, just click on the + on the left of body, and find the element with the class=centered on it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not the right picture. Your screenshot should show the <div id="graphs" class="centered"> CSS properties. Please link a picture of this windows and we will be able to help you.

Comment: fixed it thanks for the css. i posted a parameter tweak bellow

Answer (score 0):

Got it! 
simply set responsive=True. with the Luis proposed above.

```
fig = figure(title="Menu Items Streaming", x_range=FactorRange(factors=menu_items), plot_width=1000,  responsive = True)
```

[image: centered plots!]